# what is the difference between names and colnames

Tags: r, dataframe, names

I just want to understand if there is a difference between `names` and `colnames` when working with `data.frame`. Both seems to behave the same way. Can I subsitute one by the other?

Comment: From `?colnames`: "For a data frame, `rownames` and `colnames` eventually call `row.names` and `names` respectively, but the latter are preferred."

Answer (score 43):

Are they the same for data.frames? **YES**

Are they the same in general?
Not quite--the big difference is that **colnames** also works for *matrices*, whereas **names** does not (just *dataframes*).

In addition, you *can* use **names** to set/get the names of vectors (and, for obvious reasons, you can't do this with **colnames**--the result is NULL for getting and an error for setting).

Comment: `names` works on vectors too. And it actually does work on matrices... it just does not do what you expect it to do!

Comment: Re: "names" and matrices--that's kind of a loose notion of "working"... Nevertheless, point taken.

Comment: just kidding, was mostly to point out that it won't throw an error, and in some cases it may slip through :)

Comment: @SteveS Can you precise "for obvious reasons"? Doesn't seem so obvious to me ;)

Comment: @AurélienGasser, you're right: I'm not even sure myself why I thought that was so obvious at the time... But to answer your question, **colnames** only works for matrix-like objects with at least two dimensions (since it must have rows *and* columns) and, as a result, it doesn't work for vectors (since they don't have columns (or even a 'dim' attribute)).

Comment: `names()` does not work for just data.frames but also lists (no?). Example: `x <- list(); x[["a"]] <- 2; x[["b"]] <- "foo"; names(x) <- c("c", "d")`

Comment: A data.frame is a list, and that's likely why `names<-` works on data.frames

Answer (score 14):

If you look at the beginning of the `colnames` and `colnames<-` functions source code :

```
R> colnames
function (x, do.NULL = TRUE, prefix = "col") 
{
    if (is.data.frame(x) && do.NULL) 
        return(names(x))
(...)


R> `colnames<-`
function (x, value) 
{
    if (is.data.frame(x)) {
        names(x) <- value
    }
(...)
```

You can see that for data frames, `colnames` just call the `names` function. So yes, they are strictly equivalent.

Answer (score 6):

`names()` creates name attributes where as `colnames()`simply names the columns.

**i.e.**

Create a temp variable.

```
> temp <- rbind(cbind(1,2,3,4,5),
+               cbind(6,7,8,9,10))

> temp
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
[2,]    6    7    8    9   10
```

Create the `names.temp` object.

```
> names.temp <- temp
```

Use `names()` on `names.temp`

```
> names(names.temp) <- paste(c("First col", "Second col", "Third col",
 "Fourth Col", "Fifth col"))

> names.temp
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
[2,]    6    7    8    9   10
attr(,"names")
 [1] "First col"  "Second col" "Third col"  "Fourth Col" "Fifth col"  
 NA NA NA          
 [9] NA NA
```

We see here we can actually call the 5th name attribute in `names.temp`.

```
> names(names.temp)[5]
[1] "Fifth col"
```

Repeat with a second object but this time create the `colnames.temp` object.

```
> colnames.temp <- temp
```

Use `colnames()` on `colnames.temp`

```
> colnames(colnames.temp) <- paste(c("First col", "Second col", "Third col",
 "Fourth Col", "Fifth col"))

> colnames.temp
     First col Second col Third col Fourth Col Fifth col
[1,]         1          2         3          4         5
[2,]         6          7         8          9        10
```

Now name attribute is NULL.

```
> names(colnames.temp)[5]
NULL
```

FINALLY.  Let's look at our trusty `str()` command.  We can see there is a *structural difference* between `names.temp` and `colnames.temp`.  Specifically, `colnames.temp` has `dimnames` attributes not `names` attributes.

```
> str(names.temp)
 num [1:2, 1:5] 1 6 2 7 3 8 4 9 5 10
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:10] "First col" "Second col" "Thrid col" "Fourth     
Col" ...
> str(colnames.temp)
 num [1:2, 1:5] 1 6 2 7 3 8 4 9 5 10
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:5] "First col" "Second col" "Thrid col" "Fourth Col" ...
```

Comment: Nice first answer, but `names()` does not create names. `names<-` does. It is a different function.

Comment: I stand corrected.  The implication (read assumption) was to invoke `names()` implies the desire to name which is poor logic.  Thanks Frank.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am concerned, the only difference between `names()` and `colnames()` with respect to a `data.frame` input is that they allocated memory slightly differently.  For instance, consider the code chunk below:

```
    df <- data.frame(x=1:5, y=6:10, z=11:15)
    tracemem(df)
    names(df) <- c("A", "B", "C")
    colnames(df) <- c('a','b','c')
```

If you run this code, you will see that the copying of `df` only occurs once during the `names()` call, whereas the copying of `df` occurs twice during the `colnames()` call.

Comment: If you don't like copying, use `data.table::setnames` (which you can use on data.frames).