# how to select columns which share specific name in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I am sorry to ask question which could be very simple. I have a data frame which I try to put the dput below.

```
mydf <- structure(list(br.Id = c(1992.0001, 1992.0002, 1992.0003, 1992.0004, 
1992.0005, 1992.0006, 1992.0007, 1992.0008, 1992.0009, 1992.001
), si.month = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), br.day = c(23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L), br.year = c(1992L, 
1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L
), branch = 1:10, br.location = c(160170L, 160170L, 160170L, 160170L, 
160170L, 160170L, 160170L, 160170L, 160170L, 160170L), si.length = c(90L, 
128L, 112L, 68L, 56L, 58L, 111L, 111L, 115L, 65L), si.weight = c(9.3, 
32.5, 19, 4.4, 2.1, 2.8, 16.1, 17.9, 22.7, 3.4), si.sex = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("female", "male", 
"unknown"), class = "factor"), maturity = structure(c(7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 10L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 2L), .Label = c("developing", "immature", 
"mature", "nearly.ripe", "nearly.spent", "recovering", "ripe", 
"running", "spent", "unknown", "yoy"), class = "factor"), age = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L)), .Names = c("br.Id", "si.month", 
"br.day", "br.year", "branch", "br.location", "si.length", "si.weight", 
"si.sex", "maturity", "age"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

what I am trying to do is to select specific columns which share the same name as br. so the output should look like

```
      br.Id br.day br.year branch br.location
1  1992.000     23    1992      1      160170
2  1992.000     23    1992      2      160170
3  1992.000     23    1992      3      160170
4  1992.000     23    1992      4      160170
5  1992.001     23    1992      5      160170
6  1992.001     23    1992      6      160170
7  1992.001     23    1992      7      160170
8  1992.001     23    1992      8      160170
9  1992.001     23    1992      9      160170
10 1992.001     23    1992     10      160170
```

I thought maybe grep can be used to get these columns but I could not figure out how to use it. I thank you for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this

```
mydf[,grep(colnames(mydf),pattern="br.",fixed = TRUE)]
```

Comment: thanks it helped me a lot to know how to use the grep for my data

Answer (score 5):

You can use this probably ?
One way is to use dplyr package. You need to load that `library(dplyr)`. Then the **select** function is a known dplyr function used to select variables and then you can use **contains** to get those columns with specific letters in them out.

```
mydf %>% select(contains("br"))

#br.Id br.day br.year branch br.location
#1  1992.000     23    1992      1      160170
#2  1992.000     23    1992      2      160170
#3  1992.000     23    1992      3      160170
#4  1992.000     23    1992      4      160170
#5  1992.001     23    1992      5      160170
#6  1992.001     23    1992      6      160170
#7  1992.001     23    1992      7      160170
#8  1992.001     23    1992      8      160170
#9  1992.001     23    1992      9      160170
#10 1992.001     23    1992     10      160170
```

Comment: thanks, I cannot like your answer because I am new but thank you thank you to show me something which I even could not imagine !

Answer (score 4):

Or using `grepl`:

```
mydf[,grepl("br.",colnames(mydf))]
```

Or using `regexpr`:

```
mydf[,regexpr("br.",colnames(mydf))>0]
```

Or using `str_detect` from `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
mydf[,str_detect(colnames(mydf),"br.")]
```

Comment: I enjoy the regexpr, I liked your solution !

Comment: @m0h3n thanks, I cannot like your answer because I am new but thank you thank you to show me other ways

Answer (score 2):

```
mydf[, grep("^br.", names(mydf))]
```

Comment: Note that names is equivalent to colnames: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24799153/what-is-the-difference-between-names-and-colnames

Comment: `names()` is equivalent to `colnames()` for **data frames**

Comment: @RichardScriven Thanks.