# Get column name based on column data in R

Tags: r, indexing

I am trying to get the name of a data.frame column based on its contents in R.
For instance, in

```
dd= data.frame(col1=c(1,2,3), col2=c(4,5,6), col3=c(4,4,4))
```

I am looking for a something that returns `col1` when I feed it `c(1,2,3)`.

I found this [advice elsewhere](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/How-to-retrieve-a-column-name-of-a-data-frame-td4351764.html) but it does not work for me; when, as suggested, I try this

```
colnames(dd)[which(dd == c(1,2,3), arr.ind = TRUE)] 
colnames(dd)[which(dd == c(1,2,3), arr.ind = TRUE)[2]]
```

it returns all kinds of things, here the result for the 1st:

```
[1] "col1" "col2" "col3" "col1" "col1" "col1"
```

- What is the best way to do this?
- Is the above approach right; can you explain what exactly it does?
- I was surprised not to find anything on this here; if it's a duplicate, I'd be glad for links / search terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way using `identical`,

```
names(dd)[sapply(dd, function(i)identical(i, c(1, 2, 3)))]
#[1] "col1"

names(dd)[sapply(dd, function(i)identical(i, c(4, 5, 6)))]
#[1] "col2"
```

Comment: Also `setequal` if OP wants same contents, but to allow for different order / count of each unique element.

Comment: Nice, works beautifully, thanks for the help! Quick follow-up question: is there any advantage/difference to using `names` over `colnames`? They seem to be giving me the same result.

Comment: Well for data frames those 2 are the same. However, `names` does not work on matrices. That is as far as I know

Comment: ahhh...here. [This will clarify it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24799153/what-is-the-difference-between-names-and-colnames) for you