# How to index when using colnames to create a list with all colnames in R(data frames)

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, data-science

I have a problem regarding the following issue:

I need all columnames aport from V1 till the end V200 in a list, but I don't know how and where to insert the index into these lines of code.
Like this, it gives me a list of all columnames but I don't need the first two. Please help, thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GMIQ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update,** once more, thanks to akrun for a better/shorter solution:

```
names(df)[3:ncol(df)]
```

For dataframes there is no need to use `colnames`, it's the same like `names`. [The difference is only in case you're dealing with matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24799304/12242625)

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you have some good resources regarding R and indexing, working with data frames etc. could be a book, website, tutorials or so for me ?

Comment: I just checked. I'm having [this book (R for data science)](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/index.html) in German, but in English it might be even better. In general, the O'Reilly books are mostly very good and the mentioned book give you a very good overview.

Comment: PS: or in general youtube videos. If your searching for "R tutorial", you'll find many good results.

Comment: `3:ncol(df)` is shorter

Comment: thanks akrun (like many times before), I've updated it.